# Filter out script tag in snippet's javascript

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I just bumped into this question on SO: [JavaScript alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729782/javascript-alert).

The user used the new, nice Stack Snippets functionality. I tried to run the snippet, but it didn't work. The source of the problem was the `script` tag the user added to the JavaScript part of the snippets.

The resulting HTML in the SE web site was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <script language="javascript">
```

That obviously doesn't work.

Chrome says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I understand the OP should remove it, but can we help a little by removing it for him, or give a warning to let OP remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this issue is widespread enough to make it automatic.

You can easily edit it out, although the script in the question in question contains various other errors, so it still does not run.

Comment: But how would anyone know that without actually debugging the SE code?

Comment: @PatrickHofman How did you figure it out? `Unexpected token <` I assume.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I found it. Updated question.